# Swipe Horizontal

Tags: android, viewpage

I need to swipe horizontally between list of questions and their respective choices in a radio group. I have read that I have different choices such as:
1- Gesture Detector
2- ViewPage
3- ViewPage with fragments

I have tried ViewPage but I am facing different problems on how to swipe backward and indicating which choice has been checked by the user.
I need to use the easiest way to swipe forward and backward (indicating which choice has been checked)

I want to depend on Andriod methods as much as possible without storing the checked choices for example by myself since I believe that it is more optimized such methods from both run-time or code size.
Please if there are other classes that I can use, guide me on that or which of them is really the best to perform my target

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. The items of the adapter would be different instances of the same fragment. Each fragment would  contain a static question text and a radio group of possible answers to the question. 
`ViewPager` then will take care of swiping substituting one such fragment with another.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this Library:

[ViewPagerIndicator by Jake Warton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Is very customizable.

Answer (score 0):

You can easilly use the gesture detector creating a class that extend `SimpleOnGestureListener` that possess the `onFling` methods like that :

```
protected class ExampleGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {// User swipe vertically
        }
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) {// Right swipe
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) {// Left swipe
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

You just have to define the variable as you want, create your gestureDetector like

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new ExampleGestureDetector());
```

And redefine the touch listener for the view you want

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View wv, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

EDIT : After testing it, it appear that it only work with scrollable item.